# how to get the load balancer dns name using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

I have just started with Terraform today and inherited some code, so please excuse the noob question.

This is the project structure, stripped down for simplicity.

```
my-infra/modules/lb/main.tf
my-infra/modules/lb/outputs.tf
my-infra/modules/lb/terraform.tf
my-infra/modules/lb/vars.tf
my-infra/main.tf
my-infra/web-server
my-infra/api-server
```

Here in `my-infra/modules/lb/outputs.tf`, I have output a loadbalancer dnsname like this

```
output "lb_dns_name" {
  value       = aws_lb.this.dns_name
  description = "DNS name of ALB."
}
```

Here in `my-infra/main.tf`, I have this code

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

# data "aws_lb" "api_lb_dns" {
#   source = "./modules/lb"
#   dns_name = "${output.lb_dns_name}"
# }
```

I am trying to use this in `my-infra/web-server` using the code below

```
locals {
  source = "./modules/lb"
  app_name = "CS-WEB-${data.aws_region.current.id}"
  api_lb = "${output.lb_dns_name}"

}
```

This gives an error:

> A managed resource "output" "lb_dns_name" has not been declared in
> the root module.

Now if I uncomment the lines in the main.tf and try this

```
locals {
  source = "./modules/lb"
  app_name = "CS-WEB-${data.aws_region.current.id}"
  api_lb = data.aws_lb.api_lb_dns.dns_name

}
```

I get the same error

> A managed resource "output" "lb_dns_name" has not been declared in
> the root module.

What is needed to be done to fix this?

Comment: Why use modules in the locals block? Even if it were to work, you are not using a correct way of specifying a module output. Instead of `dns_name = "${output.lb_dns_name}"` it should be `dns_name = module.<logical_module_name>.lb_dns_name`.

Comment: @MarkoE: Thanks for the reply. What is `logical_module_name` here?

Answer (score 0):

This part isn't going to work at all:

```
locals {
  source = "./modules/lb"
  app_name = "CS-WEB-${data.aws_region.current.id}"
  api_lb = "${output.lb_dns_name}"
}
```

That looks like you just made up some new Terraform syntax without looking into how to actually [include a module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/modules/module) in your Terraform code. Just delete that `source` and `api_lb` in the locals block because none of that is going to work like you want.

---

Assuming `my-infra/main.tf` includes your load balancer module like this (which it should in order for you to actually use the module):

```
module "lb" {
  source = "modules/lb"
  # Other module settings here
}
```

Then you would reference the DNS name of the load balancer inside `my-infra/main.tf` using `module.lb.output.lb_dns_name`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the way you are currently trying to call the module (inside the `locals` block) will not work. Additionally, you are trying to get the output in way which also will not work. To fix that, you need to call the module properly first:

```
module "my_alb_module" {
  source = "./modules/lb"

  # the rest of the configuration goes here
  # i.e., the module input variables along with values assigned to them
}
```

Then, to get the output of the module, you would use the module keyword, the logical name (`my_alb_module`) given to the module, and the last part is the module output name:

```
output "lb_dns_name" {
  value = module.my_alb_module.lb_dns_name
}
```

This would of course be done inside `my-infra/web-server` or wherever you need the DNS name of the LB. Note however that calling the module multiple times will create the same number of LBs as there are invocations of the module.

Make sure you understand how [modules](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules) and [module outputs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/syntax#accessing-module-output-values) work. If you really need the DNS name of the LB in the local variables, this should work:

```
locals {
  api_lb = module.my_alb_module.lb_dns_name
}
```